# How to configure a filter to work after servlet processing?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

The problem in brief is that i want a certain filter to run after servlet processing to check for a value in the request attributes and based on that value it redirects to a certain URl.

In web.xml,

i have put the  element the last in order, and in side the doFilter method i call "chain.doFilter(request, response);" the first line then my logic executes afterwards.

thats in tomcat 5.5, it works fine on two local machines but other testing machines it does not, there is a slight difference in the tomcat versions, on the local machines its tomcat 5.5.17 while on the testing servers its 5.5.27.

do have any idea what the problem could be? , i appreciate sharing the answer, thanks

web.xml

```
<!-- #########################################################################
   ## Filters
   ######################################################################### -->

 <filter>
    <filter-name>other filters</filter-name>

  </filter>
    .
    .
    .
  <filter>
   <filter-name>UrlRedirectFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>......filter.UrlRedirectFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
    .
    .
    .

  <filter>
    <filter-name>other filters</filter-name>

  </filter>


<!-- #########################################################################
      ## Filter Mappings
     ######################################################################### -->


  <filter-mapping>
     . 
     .
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>UrlRedirectFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>

  <!-- #########################################################################
   ## Servlet context listeners for application initialization.
   ######################################################################### -->

  <listener>
     <listener-class>....</listener-class>
  </listener>


  <!-- #########################################################################
       ## Servlets
       ######################################################################### -->



  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>...</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>..</servlet-class>
  </servlet>


  <!-- #########################################################################
        ## Servlet mappings
       ######################################################################### -->

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>...</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>...</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>



  <!-- #########################################################################
   ## Welcome File List
   ######################################################################### -->


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>_ignorewelcomefiles_</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- #########################################################################
       ## Error Pages
       ######################################################################### -->

 </web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that everything is fine:

1. Check the logs for any hints
2. Add a logging message / `System.out.println` / breakpoint after the `chain.doFilter(..)` line and see if it is actually executed.

Comment: I would also like to add, Try putting code in Try block and printstacktrace in catch block also check if logger is configured properly

Comment: i tried adding the system.out.line and yes it is not executed.

Comment: @Amr then paste here your web.xml fragment. And the Filter code

Comment: if one of the filters throw an exception it will stop the filter chain execution, am i right?

Comment: because it seems that one of the filters throw an exception on the testing servers , while that did not happen on the local machine.so if i am right and the chain will stop execution after throwing an exception.. then its clear now where the problem is...unfortunately,i have no idea about the other filters ... sorry for bothering you ...

Comment: @Bozho: does it make sense? or still want to see the fragments and the code.

Comment: the chain does not stop, but the exception is thrown up, and ends in the log files. Hence the 1st point in my answer ;)

Comment: after tracing the code with the "out" statements... i found nothing but the filter runs before the servlet processing...

Comment: yes, the filter runs before the servlet, then chain.doFilter() invokes the servlet, and the code after it is ran after the servlet

Comment: @Amr: you need to fix the cause of this exception, then the filter will continue its code logic as expected. If you have trouble fixing this exception, ask a question and include all detail about the exception and trace.

Comment: I fixed the cause of the exception and then i added three "system.out" statements , one before chain.doFilter(), one after chain.doFilter(), and one inside the filter:       and they were printed like the following, 1. Inside the servlet 2. before the chain.doFilter 3.after the chain.doFilter

Comment: I figured out the cause of the problem, it is because that i have another filters that works on the url mapping pattern differently on production servers from the local machine .. which cuts the chain of execution , and probably that's why i suffer... Thanks you all how tried to help